# Apple ios distribution certificate has same apple id for 2 different distribution certificate

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I have 2 distribution Provisioning Profiles,both has the same App Id

Profile 1: using which an app was already in app store

if I upload an ipa to itunes using Profile 2(same App Id), will that update my old app(which was uploaded using the Profile 1) in the itunes?

Comment: Is really provisioning profile changes required? why not profile 1?

Comment: if the second provisional profile generated by old profile bundle id then yes it will be update. (for the update an app provisional profile must be generated by application bundle id if that are change you even dont select that provisonal profile at sign the ipa file)

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't change anything and will successfully update your app if the `App Id` is the same. It doesn't matter how many Provisioning Profiles you have for the same app.